# BeautifulSoup, pandas: Объединение столбцов с одинаковым названием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautiful-soup

Что сделано

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_upcoming_events(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    events_dict = {}
    i = 0
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    events = soup.find('div', {'class': 'events-box'}).findAll('div', {'class', 'unit span4 event '})

    for event in events:
        event_type = event.find('small').text
        event_title = event.find('h3', {'class', 'title'}).text
        event_desc = event.find('p', {'itemprop': 'description'}).text
        events_dict[i] = [event_type, event_title, event_desc]
        i += 1

    get_upcoming_events('https://runet-id.com/events/')
events_dict
```

далее почистила данные.

Есть датафрэйм с данными. Выглядит как таблица с 27 столбцами и 2 строками. Как можно объединить столбцы с одинаковыми названиями так, чтобы все значения в самих столбцах сохранились ? (например, нужно сделать один столбец "Другие мероприятия", чтобы в строках сохранились все другие значения из существующих множественных столбцов "Другие мероприятия")

```
df = pd.DataFrame(events_dict)
```

PS не прикладывается таблица в печатном виде, уж извиняйте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовала такой путь, но ошибка

```
result = df.merge('Другие мероприятия')
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>
```

> после прогонки одного из ответов
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете приложить входные данные, они у вас в словаре? Значения из столбцов "Вебинар" и "Конференция" тоже нужно объединить?

Comment: @Andrey вставила в вопрос

Comment: То есть, в результате вы хотите получить 3 столбца и 27 строк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, можно просто переписать функцию `get_upcoming_events`, чтобы она возвращала список, элементы которого - словари. Каждый словарь - одно мероприятие.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_upcoming_events(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    events = soup.find('div', {'class': 'events-box'}).findAll('div', {'class', 'unit span4 event '})

    return [
        {
            'Тип мероприятия': event.find('small').text,
            'Название': event.find('h3', {'class', 'title'}).text,
            'Описание': event.find('p', {'itemprop': 'description'}).text,
        }
        for event in events]


events = get_upcoming_events('https://runet-id.com/events/')

df = pd.DataFrame(events)
df
```

Результат:

```
                                             Название                                           Описание     Тип мероприятия
0                                      школа Serenity  Учим комплексному маркетингу на реальных проек...  Другие мероприятия
1                                       CRM и ПРОДАЖИ  Компания amoCRM запускает тур бесплатных бизне...  Другие мероприятия
2     Бесплатный вебинар: 7 шагов к успешному бизнесу  Вебинар будет полезен тем, кто задумался об от...             Вебинар
3                            Social Media Moscow 2019  19 июня 2019 года вновь состоится конференция ...         Конференция
4                      Технологии доверия. Trust tech  Узнайте про будущее рынка персональных данных ...  Другие мероприятия
5                           CLIENT SERVICE FORUM 2019  19, 20, 21 июня компания InterForum в четверты...         Конференция
6   МарТех.Медицина: конференция для маркетологов ...  Конференция о digital-технологиях для маркетол...  Другие мероприятия
7   Netpeak Business Talks — всё о продвижении биз...  20 июня в Алматы пройдет мероприятие Netpeak B...  Другие мероприятия
8   Бизнес-завтрак «Эффективный маркетинг для прои...  20 июня 2019 интернет-агентство «Амадо» провед...  Другие мероприятия
9   Конференция «SEO MOSCOW 2019: ВЗРЫВ ПРОДАЖ ВАШ...  Приглашаем вас 20 июня 2019 в 12.00 посетить к...  Другие мероприятия
10  20 вопросов, на которые должен ответить b2b-ма...    Вебинар Андрея Гаврикова, гендиректора Комплето         Конференция
11               Как запустить свой IT-бизнес с нуля?   3-дневный интенсив по созданию IT-бизнеса с нуля  Другие мероприятия
12  BCL «Правовые основы и юридические практики ра...  24 июня в РЭУ имени Г.В. Плеханова начинается ...  Другие мероприятия
13  Как отстроиться от конкурентов с помощью позиц...  В результате вы получите не просто лекционный ...     Семинар тренинг
14  Информационная безопасность крупных web и mobi...  25 июня Ростелеком, Эльдорадо и AGIMA проведут...  Другие мероприятия
15                                Собрание РОЦИТ 2019  К участию приглашены действующие члены организ...  Другие мероприятия
16                          Собрание Членов РАЭК 2019  Очередное Общее собрание членов РАЭК проводитс...  Другие мероприятия
17                                    BIG IЮНЬ-DAY #9  25 июня 2019 года на в офисе РАЭК состоится оч...  Другие мероприятия
18                                   GR-Клуб при РАЭК        В феврале 2019 года РАЭК запустила GR-клуб.  Другие мероприятия
19      Летняя дискуссия о серьезном маркетинге в B2B  25 июня, с 16.00-20.00 в коворкинге SOK пройде...  Другие мероприятия
20                Рабочая группа РАЭК по телемедицине  25 июня в 16:00 состоится Рабочая группа РАЭК ...  Другие мероприятия
21  Бесплатный вебинар: Как собрать эффективную ко...  Это – вебинар для предпринимателей микро-, мал...             Вебинар
22      Вводный вебинар в мир CRM-систем  для бизнеса  Четко структурированная информация\r\n\r\nГрам...             Вебинар
23   Форум о создании сильных команд #DreamTeam Forum       Мероприятие соберет 500 гостей, 25 спикеров.  Другие мероприятия
24                Personal Assistant Summer Club 2019  27-28 июня в Москве пройдёт четвертая ежегодна...  Другие мероприятия
25     Crimean Business Week 2019 «Тренды будущего»,   27-30 июня в Алуште состоится Crimean Business...  Другие мероприятия
26                                        FINCH&DICH`  28 июня в 19:00 FINCH приглашает к себе в офис...  Другие мероприятия
27             Однодневный интенсив «PR для стартапа»  После интенсива вы сможете:\r\n•\tСпланировать...     Семинар тренинг
28                                     НеФорум Москва  Бесплатная конференция о блогосфере Рунета для...         Конференция
```

Comment: можете проверить код, у меня после прогона выдает "-"

Comment: У меня он работает, само собой. Как вы запускаете? Вы пользуетесь Jupyter? Встаьте весь код в отдельную ячейку и выполните.

Comment: да, юпитер, вставила еще раз и прогнала. код работает, но выдает почему-то на выходе черточку

Comment: можете сделать снимок экрана?

Comment: вставила снимок в свой вопрос @Andrey

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема. Попробуйте 2 последние строки (создание и вывод датафрейма) перенести в отдельную ячейку и запустить. Еще попробуйте перезапустить ядро: пункт меню Kernel > Restart и снова выполнить код.

Comment: попробовала сделать как вы сказали, то же самое @Andrey хэлп))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95024/discussion-between-andrey-and-user329688).

Comment: если вам не трудно, давайте продолжим здесь. трудности с аккаунтом.

Comment: Хорошо. Попробуйте отдельно вывести `events`, подозреваю, что функция возвращает пустой список. Если так, то в теле функции попробуйте добавить `print(req)` и `print(soup)`, чтобы посмотреть что там вообще происходит.

Comment: да, словарь events возвращает пустой словарь. когда вставила print(req) и -print(soup) ответ Response [200] и полный код запрашиваемой страницы

Comment: В коде страницы есть нужные элементы? Что выводит `print(events)`, если его поместить в тело функции?

Comment: разместила print(events) после events = soup.find('div', {'class': 'events-box'}).findAll('div', {'class', 'unit span4 event'}) в выводе получила "[ ]" В коде страницы есть все элементы, как нужные, так и лишние.

Comment: Так, попробуйте использовать `events = soup.find('div', {'class': 'events-box'}).findAll('div', {'class', 'unit span4 event '})` - это строчка из вашего вопроса. Она отличается от того, что я написал пробелом в `'unit span4 event '`

Comment: эврика! дополните это в своем ответе выше

Comment: Изменил ответ. Хотя у меня как раз код с пробелом не работает. Ничего не понял, ну да ладно.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых вы неверно используете метод `merge`.
Во-вторых, судя по вопросу, вам нужен метод `groupby`:

Честно признаюсь, для меня решение не тривиальное, поэтому я рекомендую воспользоваться уже существующим [решением](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390645/python-pandas-merge-samed-name-columns-in-a-dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["а","б","в"],["г","д","е"]], 
    columns=["Один", "Два", "Один"])

print(df)
```

Исходный датасет:

```
  Один Два Один
0    а   б    в
1    г   д    е

#собственно, решение:
def sjoin(x):
    return '; '.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))

res = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(sjoin, axis=1))
```

Получаем:

```
  Два  Один
0   б  а; в
1   д  г; е
```

Только имейте в виду, что это решение сработает для всех колонок с одинаковыми именами.

**UPDATE**

Если вам просто нужно "разуникалить" имена колонок, то предлагаю воспользоваться простым способом, не прибегая к `merge` и т. д.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["а","б","в"],["г","д","е"]], 
    columns=["Один", "Два", "Один"])

tmp=[]
res =[]
for col in range(len(df.columns)):
    tmp.append(df.columns[col])
    res.append(df.columns[col]+str(tmp.count(df.columns[col])))

df.columns=res
```

получим:

```
  Один1 Два1 Один2
0     а    б     в
1     г    д     е
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, возможно есть способ сделать так, каждое мероприятие под бывшими столбцами "Другие мероприятия" записались отдельно в новые строки/колонки ?

Comment: Обновил ответ, такое решение вас устроит?

Comment: нет, так как задача моя в том, чтобы в столбцах был тип новости("другие мероприятия", "семинары"...), а в строках заголовки (сам текст, который мы достали с сайта)